# Lbutton event seems to disable my dragging

Tags: autohotkey

```
LButton::
MouseClick, Left 
if(recodring==true){
    mouseGetPos, x, y
    xPosPlan[pos] := x
    yPosPlan[pos] := y
    xPosPlan.push(0)
    yPosPlan.push(0)
    timePlan.push(0)
    pos := pos + 1

return
}
```

I made a script that records mouse clicks but in this part I dont know why left button dragging got disabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that when you press the left button down, the script intercepts that event and presses the left button down and up again. Try replacing

```
LButton::
MouseClick, Left
```

by

```
~LButton::
```

. This will make the script not intercept that event inthe first place.